# How to run MR1 on Hadoop 2.x(yarn , clourera 5.x)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I have written a code in MR1 in eclipse and it runs file usng the hadoop 2.x jars . The following is my maven configuration

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now I want to run this job on a already set cluster running hadoop 2.6 on cloudera 5.x using Yarn as the resource manager.

So now I wanted to execute my MR1 from my eclipse (OS is Ubuntu) on the hadoop cluster set up already.

So what all configuration Do i need to do to submit my job correctly.

I am having a Configuration Object to set all the requested parameters to submit.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
```

And Passing this in my JobConf Object

```
 JobConf conf = new JobConf(configuration, Driver.class);
```

Kindly advice as to what all properties must be set in in the configuration object to submit my job on the cloudera cluster

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: You want to run a map reduce in local eclipse, which was already running in cluster? Can you please clarify. Also which command are you using to run cluster. Mostly, the quorum details need to be modified.

Comment: hi @Ramzy, thanks for replying, I am not trying to run a mapreduce which was running in a cluster, it is like I made a mapreduce (MR1) and tested it in local mode using hadoop 2.6 and it was working fine. Next I want to run it in distributed mode, so what all hadoop configurations do I need to do for job written in MR1 to to run it in my hadoop cluster. Yes I am running the code from my eclipse and hoping to submit it to hadoop cluster running in Yarn.